# What is the antonym to 'elevation'?

Tags: american-english, antonyms

How do I say an opposite of "elevation of an object over the plane" which would mean "the level of the displacement of an object under the plane"? That is, I am looking for a word in "??? of an object under the plane"

Comment: The opposite of the 'angle of elevation' is the 'angle of _depression_'. For distances, you may have to use say 'depth below the plane'.

Comment: Yep, the opposite of elevation is depression.

Comment: *Distance* from the plane for an object lying below the plane (where z < 0).